# jqplot gradientcolor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, gradient, jqplot

I'm using [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/). Is there a way to set a custom gradientcolor to each slice of my piechart? I'm using the seriescolor option:

```
seriesColors: ["#F3CBBF", "#BFDDE5", "#CF3501"],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are placing the 'seriesColors' option inside the 'seriesDefaults' object.

A simple example:

```
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('div1', [['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6]], {
        title: 'Chart 1',

            seriesDefaults:{
                renderer:$.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions:{
                  showDataLabels: true,
                  dataLabels:'percent'
            }
            },
            seriesColors: ["#F3CBBF", "#BFDDE5", "#CF3501"],
            highlighter: {
                show: true
        },
            legend: {
                        show:true,
                        location: 's', 
                        placement: 'outsideGrid'}
        });
```

Make sure to include the pie renderer javascript file as well as the jqplot-css file (if you want to display the legend)

Answer (score 0):

jqPlot pie charts don't support gradients out of the box.  There's no property setting in the API (http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html).  You'd most likely have to do this in CSS, HTML 5 and/or in the canvas object.  Unfortunately, you'd also run afoul of different browsers treating gradients differently.  jqPlot bubble charts have a gradient property, though I know that doesn't help beyond letting you know that there is a chart type that does do that (http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-bubbleRenderer-js.html).

```
seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        bubbleAlpha: 0.7,
        varyBubbleColors: false,
        bubbleGradients: true
    }
}
```